# How to make table columns more even?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using Bootstrap to build a website that calculates some one-variable statistics and displays the result. However, when the results are displayed, the table looks very uneven, as shown here (in the bottom table:

[image: here]

The contents of the table rows are filled by a JavaScript function (which does work).

```css
.table {
  width: 80vw;
  content-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Statistics</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous">     </script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Mean</th>
          <th scope="col">Mode</th>
          <th scope="col">Standard Deviation</th>
          <th scope="col">Variance</th>
          <th scope="col">Range</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="others">

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: You mean make the _columns_ more even?

Comment: Is that two separate tables? Please update the demo I created with your code to accurately show the problem.

Comment: The code shown doesn't produce the output described.  A single row in a single table "looks even" to me.  As for the output described, how specifically are you trying to "make it even"?  Are you trying to assign specific widths to columns?  Something else?  Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate specifically what isn't working as expected in your attempt.

Comment: If you need both tables to look even, you need to create either a CSS class for the cells or select them directly using a selector and apply your desired width to even them out.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-striped table-hover responsive" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>    
        <th>Col4</th>
        <th>Col5</th>
        <th>Col6</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>hi 1</td>
          <td>hi 2</td>
          <td>hi 3</td>
          <td>hi 4</td>
          <td>hi 5</td>    
          <td>hi 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>hi 1</td>
          <td>hi 2</td>
          <td>hi 3</td>
          <td>hi 4</td>
          <td>hi 5</td>    
          <td>hi 6</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -2):

1- THs needs to be inside a TR (table row)
2- TH and TD needs to match (use colspan to match if you don't have the relative TD).

```
<tbody>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>    
      <th>Col4</th>
      <th>Col5</th>
      <th>Col6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="others">
      <td colspan="6"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</tbody>
```